# Correct show images in a switch case function?(Android)

Tags: android

So I need to show one of the images according to my switch case function, and I don't really know what would be the best way to do it. Do I really need to put them in an xml file, can I just draw them in the function? Also, do I need to put this function in an activity?

I can provide you my switch case function:

```
public void BloodStatistics(){
        String state;
        int cases=1;
        switch(cases){
        case 1: if(sys<90 && dys<60)
            state="Hypotension";
        break;
        case 2: if(sys>90 && sys<119 && dys>60 && dys<79)
            state="Desriable";
        break;
        case 3: if(sys>120 && sys<139 && dys>80 && dys<89)
            state="Prehypertension";
        break;
        case 4: if(sys>140 && sys<159 && dys>90 && dys<99)
            state="Hypertension Stage 1";
        break;
        case 5: if(sys>160 && sys<179 && dys>100 && dys<109)
            state="Hypertension Stage 2";
        break;
        case 6: if(sys>=180 && dys>=110)
            state="Hypertension Crisis";
        break;
        case 7: if(sys<90 && dys>=60)
            state="Hypotension";
        break;
        default: state="invalid mesurements";
        break;

        }
    }
```

and these are my images:

```
ImageView Hypotension, Desriable, Prehypertension, Hypertension_Stage_1, Hypertension_Stage_2, Hypertension_Crisis;
```

I'm sorry if the question seems too easy :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use one `ImageView` and then set the image into it based on your conditions. I'm also a bit confused by your switch statement.  From what I can understand, you're just checking blood pressure ranges, so I'd have the code something like this:

```
ImageView image = findViewById(R.id.status_image);
int res;

if(sys<90 && dys<60) {
    res = r.drawable.Hypotension;
}
else if(sys>90 && sys<119 && dys>60 && dys<79) {
    res = r.drawable.Desriable;
}
else if(sys>120 && sys<139 && dys>80 && dys<89) {
    res = r.drawable.Prehypertension;
}
else if(sys>140 && sys<159 && dys>90 && dys<99) {
    res = r.drawable.Hypertension_Stage_1;
}
else if(sys>160 && sys<179 && dys>100 && dys<109) {
    res = r.drawable.Hypertension_Stage_2;
}
else if(sys>=180 && dys>=110) {
    res = r.drawable.Hypertension_Crisis;
}
else if(sys<90 && dys>=60) {
    res = r.drawable.Hypotension;
}
else {
    res = 0;
}

if(res != 0) {
    image.setImageDrawable(res);
}
```

Make sure to put your images with the names you indicated into the `drawable` folder (or, better yet, different resolution versions of each image into `drawable-ldpi`, `drawable-mdpi`, `drawable-hdpi` and `drawable-xhdpi`

Comment: This is a standard and widely used method for selecting images based on some state machine etc. Make sure it all runs on the UI thread.

Comment: thanks, this made it more clear. I have only one question (maybe seems stupid) who is status_image? is it an animation or a default image?

Comment: @DianaC In your XML, you would need to name the ImageView using `id="+@id/status_image"` or something similar - to be able to refer to it.  This is the same name you used in XML.  If you didn't create the ImageView in XML, then instead of that line, you'd have something like `ImageView image = new ImageView(this);` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your `switch` does not make sense because you will always get into `case 1:`, remove the `switch`/`case` stuff and do it with `if ... else` only.

```
    String state="invalid mesurements"; // or use the R.id. here and make state int
    if(sys<90 && dys<60)
        state="Hypotension";
    if(sys>90 && sys<119 && dys>60 && dys<79)
        state="Desriable";
    if(sys>120 && sys<139 && dys>80 && dys<89)
        state="Prehypertension";
    if(sys>140 && sys<159 && dys>90 && dys<99)
        state="Hypertension Stage 1";
    if(sys>160 && sys<179 && dys>100 && dys<109)
        state="Hypertension Stage 2";
    if(sys>=180 && dys>=110)
        state="Hypertension Crisis";
    if(sys<90 && dys>=60)
        state="Hypotension";
```

be careful: if multiple `if` match the condition `state` will be overwritten so order most important case last.